# Как не обрабатывать данные с формы повторно при обновлении старницы после отправки

Tags: php

Приветствую всех вошедших

Делаем обычную форму, которая ест-но отправляет данные на страницу, которая их обрабатывает. И есть 2 пути. 1 неудобный - 2 страница, на которой нет формы. Потом от туда нужно прыгнуть обратно, туда где была форма или на 3ю страницу. 2й способ сделать, что то вроде:

```
<?
if(isset($_POST)){
    // получаем данные с формы, обрабатываем
}
?>
<form action="" ..><imput..><imput..><imput type="submit"></form>
```

И во втром способе есть минус, если отправить данные форме, они ест-но отправятся, но если потом нажать F5 - данные снова отправляются, снова F5 - снова отправляются.

Как сделать, чтобы при F5/обновлении страницы - повторной отправки не происходило?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

перенаправьте страницу через header('location: index.php'); index заменить на страницу с вашей же формой. Почему задаете одни и те же вопросы не прочитав, что уже есть написано тем более это было сегодня?

Comment: Понял как сделать. Но вопроса аналогичного не видел, не по поиску не сегодня